# When do I capitalize the word "district"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, capitalization

I am having trouble with knowing whether to lowercase or capitalize the word "district". I found two sentences that disturb me because I don't see a pattern.
**Sentence: I went to the diamond district in New York.**
I don't understand why diamond district is lowercase when it appears to me to be the name of a district?

**Sentence:The Lake District is a very romantic area**.
Yet here, what appears to be the name of a district"Lake District" is capitalized here.
**Question: why aren't the names of the districts both capitalized in each sentence?**

Comment: The diamond district refers to the area where diamonds are traded etc., but The Lake District is the geographical name af the area. Please refer to previous questions in the 'Related' panel on the right.

Comment: The 'diamond district' of New York is a description, not a name. The curry district of Birmingham also, and most large cities have a 'central business district. All (not) capitalised as here.

Answer (score 4):

When the term "district" is used as a description it is not a proper name and is not capitalized. Usages such as "the business district", "the industrial district", "the financial district", or "the historic district"  are descriptions and do not get capital letters.  Phrases such as "the Lake District" or "the Framington District" are names of places, and do get capital letters. However a frequently used description can become an informal name, particularly in a city such as New York with many fairly well-defined areas devoted to particular purposes. Descriptions such as  "the theater district" or "the diamond district" could slip into becoming "the Theater District" and "the Diamond District". The "Garment District" has, I think, already done this.